# Google Trends - Quota limit reached after 5 calls

Tags: c#, limit

I tried to implement Google Trends in my web application. This is my code:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var username = "USERNAME";
            var password = "PASSWORD";


            var response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1", username, password));

            var auth = response.Split('\n')[2];
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin " + auth);

            Uri url = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q={0}&cid=TOP_QUERIES_0_0&export=3", keyword));
            string result = client.DownloadString(url);

            result = result.Replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", string.Empty);
            result = result.Replace(");", string.Empty);
            result = result.Replace("// Data table response", string.Empty);
```

I actually just need the top queries of a keyword.
The code works fine, but after 5 queries I get an error that I've reached my quota limit.
After waiting an hour I can do two more queries and I've reached my limit again.
But I still can search keywords on the Google Trends website.

Can someone please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Christine

Comment: This is not an answer, because I'm struggling with the same problem.
But have you tried different URI to fetch data? I'm using this URI: http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en&q=apple&date=1%2F2011%203m&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1

- It gives data as text file with CSV table. But it also has top searches and other sections.
I'm just curious if google quota behavior would be different for different URI or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly Google Trends has a quota for requests. It sounds like it is connected to IP address so it would be why your search on your computer isn't affected after you do it on the phone. Also it sounds like there is a limit for fast successions of searches as well.

Not positive about this but that is how it seems.

Comment: It's a web application not a phone application. That's why I dont't understand that it's still working on the website of Google Trends but not in my application. There is a limit for requests, but why do I reach the limit just because of 5 calls?

Comment: Might be because you send the requests all at once? I'm not sure just giving a general idea that might help.

Comment: I tried it and hoped that this would be the problem. But it seems that it's not. I waited about 10 minutes after each call, but I could not even make three calls :( How is it even possible that sometimes I can send five or six requests before I reach the limit and sometimes just two or three? I really do not understand what the problem is. But thank you for your answers.